# Royalty-Free Sliders used in theme development

Tags: php, theme-development, jquery, licensing

I am wanting to develop a premium Wordpress theme, and would like to know what is the best way to go on choosing a slider.  I'm not skilled enough yet to write one from scratch.

The ideal situation for me would be to use a Royalty-free slider (slides.js?) and then create different designs from that single slider.  Is that okay?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about Anything Slider? I think it's open source.
https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  How are u?  I also found the Flexslider and slides.js. I will take a look into Anything slider as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey Rob, I'm fine. And how are you? I even didn't see that this is you. haha what's a case that we met here again lol.